# No occurrences within the custom range - fabric

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

```
"No occurrences within the custom range"
```

what does this means while using fabric for Crashlytics in Android?
I see issue mail and when I clicked this , i get the issue details but also this message at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. I'd check the date filters selected in your Crashlytics dashboard and ensure you're time range includes the day from when the email was generated.

[image: Arrow pointing to calendar and date selector in Fabric dashboard]

Comment: Hello Mike,Thanks for your reply !! It indeed resolve the issue, I can now see the issues .